# SystemStackError (stack level too deep): in my create controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `SaleQualifier` objects in my Rails app. Each one finds a pre-determined (and pre-loaded via YAML) question to display on a `SalesOpportunity` show page, and then builds an Answer `sale_qualifier has_one answer`. Both items are to be saved to the database, after which I use the answer_type and answer_text to determine which question ought to be shown to the user next.

I presume there's some kind of infinite loop going on in my code, but I can't work out what it is. This worked fine when I had a `sale_qualifier has_many answers` relationship, but it broke as soon as I changed the relationship to a `has_one` relationship.

My code:

```
 def show
  @sales_opportunity = SalesOpportunity.includes(:company, :user, :timeline_events, :sale_contacts, :swots, :sale_competitors).find(params[:id])
  @sale_qualifier = SaleQualifier.new(sales_opportunity_id: params[@sales_opportunity.id])
  @answer = @sale_qualifier.answers.build
  #if the question_id is blank it is the first question in the list
   if @sale_qualifier.question_id.blank?
    @question = Question.find_by_id(@sale_qualifier.next_question_id)
   else
    @question = Question.find_by_id(@sale_qualifier.question_id)
   end
end
```

This just sets up the show action so I can display the form for adding the answer:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <%= form_for(@sale_qualifier) do |f| %>
 <% if @sale_qualifier.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
   <h2><%= pluralize(@sale_qualifier.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this answer from being saved:</h2>
   <ul>
   <% @sale_qualifier.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
     <li><%= message %></li>
   <% end %>
   </ul>
 </div>
<% end %>
<div class="panel-body">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
   <h2><%= @question.question_text %></h2>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
   <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.hidden_field :sales_opportunity_id, :value => @sales_opportunity.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :question_id, :value => @question.id %>
  </div>
   <%= f.fields_for :answers do |answer| %>
    <%= answer.text_area :answer_text, :placeholder => "Enter your answer" %>
   <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-success"%>
  </div>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Upon submission this is processed by the SaleQualifier create method:

```
  def create
  @sale_qualifier = SaleQualifier.new(sale_qualifier_params)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @sale_qualifier.save
    format.html { redirect_to @sale_qualifier, notice: 'Sale qualifier was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @sale_qualifier }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @sale_qualifier.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

But I think the error occurs in the methods I've added to the Answer and SaleQualifier models:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :answer_text, presence: true
 belongs_to :sale_qualifier
 after_save :update_sale_qualifier

 def update_sale_qualifier
    sale_qualifier.update_next_question
    sale_qualifier.save
 end
end

class SaleQualifier < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :answer, :inverse_of => :sale_qualifier, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer
 belongs_to :sales_opportunity
 validates :sales_opportunity_id, presence: true

def update_next_question
    #find the question that this SaleQualifier is associated with
    question = Question.find_by_id(self.question_id)
    #get its answer_type as this defines whether we need to look at the next_question_id_no or not
    ans_type = question.answer_type
    if ans_type == 'Text Field' || ans_type == 'Datetime' || ans_type == 'Integer' || ans_type == 'Boolean' && self.answer.answer_text == 'True'
        self.next_question_id = question.next_question_id_yes
        #if the answer_type is a boolean and the answer is no/false, then use the next_question_id_no to route the question
    elsif ans_type == 'Boolean' && self.answer.answer_text == 'False'
        self.next_question_id = question.next_question_id_no
    end
    #mark the question as answered, in case we need to iterate over the same quesiton in future
    self.has_answer = true
    #create a new SaleQualifier with the question set as the next question, unless it already exists and hasn't been answered yet or unless the next question id leads us to a result (i.e. no questions left in the tree)
    SaleQualifier.create(question_id: self.next_question_id, sales_opportunity_id: self.sales_opportunity_id) unless Question.exists?(:id => self.next_question_id) || SaleQualifier.find_by(question_id: self.next_question_id) && SaleQualifier.find_by(question_id: self.next_question_id).has_answer == false
 end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 730ms

SystemStackError (stack level too deep): actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:79
```

I'm assuming that there's a namespace error coming through here, as I've probably used the word "answer" too much in my model field names. Can anyone help me find it please?

**Edit**

The error is looping through this following set of SQL actions:

```
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "answers" SET "answer_text" = $1, "created_at" = $2, "id" = $3, "sale_qualifier_id" = $4, "updated_at" = $5 WHERE "answers"."id" = 6  [["answer_text", "Because they're Grrrreat!"], ["created_at", "2016-01-13 09:19:46.172878"], ["id", 6], ["sale_qualifier_id", 8], ["updated_at", "2016-01-13 09:19:46.172878"]]
 Question Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"  WHERE "questions"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 Question Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "questions"  WHERE "questions"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
 CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"  WHERE "questions"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "sale_qualifiers" SET "created_at" = $1, "has_answer" = $2, "id" = $3, "next_question_id" = $4, "question_id" = $5, "sales_opportunity_id" = $6, "updated_at" = $7 WHERE "sale_qualifiers"."id" = 8  [["created_at", "2016-01-13 09:19:46.164754"], ["has_answer", "t"], ["id", 8], ["next_question_id", 2], ["question_id", 1], ["sales_opportunity_id", 77], ["updated_at", "2016-01-13 09:19:46.164754"]]
 SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "answers" SET "answer_text" = $1, "created_at" = $2, "id" = $3, "sale_qualifier_id" = $4, "updated_at" = $5 WHERE "answers"."id" = 6  [["answer_text", "Because they're Grrrreat!"], ["created_at", "2016-01-13 09:19:46.172878"], ["id", 6], ["sale_qualifier_id", 8], ["updated_at", "2016-01-13 09:19:46.172878"]]
 Question Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"  WHERE "questions"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 Question Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "questions"  WHERE "questions"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
 (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Post more of the error.

Comment: This error basically means [infinite recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop)

Comment: @Zoinks10, I suggest you insert debugging code to find the line that produces the infinite loop. You can do this by using any of the following: `puts 'IM HEREEEEEEEE'`, `jsadfkljasdflkasdjfkl`, or `byebug` You would need to insert this at the start of the action first, then progressively go down. If you know `byebug`, it will be better because you can press `n` multiple times which continues to the next line, and so forth.

Comment: Thanks @Jay-ArPolidario - i have byebug installed so I'll use that.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario - it seems to be calling the update_next_question method when I save the SaleQualifier (even though it's not instructed to do this unless the answer is saved). As such it's constantly creating new SaleQualifiers according to the code at the bottom and then iterating through the update_next_question method again.

Comment: @Zoinks10 My first impression is that the looping has something to do with the inverse_of, as it makes all variables pointing the object to be accessed in just one same in-memory. This is a little tricky to debug if I am just looking at the code.

Comment: Thanks @Jay-ArPolidario - as mentioned in my question I'd originally set this up as a has_many relationship, and am refactoring it. Perhaps the inverse_of statement is no longer necessary.